# compering quantity or rate with to/per

Tags: prepositions

What's the difference  between :

> 1 This car does 30 miles to the gallon.

> 2 This car does 30 miles per gallon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macmillan dictionary [shows](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/miles-to-the-per-a-gallon) that all the three phrases are correct (the two you suggested and *miles to **a** gallon*).

> miles to the​/​per​/​a gallon
>
> ---
>
> **the number of miles a vehicle will travel using one gallon of fuel**
> *The car does 50 miles to the gallon.*

Answer (score -2):

This car does 30 miles to the gallon" is an informal idiom. In this case, "the gallon" is not a specific gallon.

This car gets 30 miles per gallon" is a more formal idiom with the same meaning.

Comment: Can you indicate what you mean by a specific gallon, and why it should not be specific after the preposition **to** but fine after **per**.